# Cryptic XmlException when trying to run azure powershell cmdlets

Tags: azure

I get similar errors trying to run a variety of Azure commands:

- New-AzureService
- Get-AzureAffinityGroup
- Get-AzureCertificate
- Get-AzureDeployment
- etc.

*Get-AzureService : The 'BR' start tag on line 6 does not match the end tag of 'FONT'. Line 7, position 3.
At line:1 char:17
+ get-azureservice <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureService], XmlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.GetAzureServiceCommand*

The only other instance of this that I've been able to find on the web was here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/4d51fd39-ca27-426d-b3dc-f3042297eaad

and that went unanswered.  The error makes it sound like there's a config file somewhere that's been modified, but I don't know where to look.  I've tried uninstalling the azure cmdlets package, and deleting all of its files, hoping that the relevant file might be regenerated on reinstallation, but no such luck.

Comment: If your edit answers the question, please post it as an answer, not an addition to the question.

Comment: I can't until my account is eight hours old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's the fix I found:

Looks like it's a proxy error.  Resetting the default web proxy's credentials fixed the error messages.  Try:

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
```